# How to constrain the integer variable staying out of an integer interval

Tags: gams-math

As mentioned in the title, how to use a **linear constrain** to ensure an integer **n** is staying out of (**n1**, **n2**), in which **n,n1,n2** are all integers, and the interval is not [**n1**, **n2**].

I formulate the problem in GAMS as

`n2 - n1 =l= abs(2*n - n2 - n1)`

but the `abs()` is not allowed in a MIP model.

THX

Comment: I think you can use .lo and .up to set bounds just as with regular continuous variables.


I.e.

    n.lo = n1;
    n.up = n2;

Comment: @MartinBonde, but I need the **n** out of the interval, and **n, n1, n2** are all integer variables.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I don't know if the '(n*n)**(1/2)' trick will work.

Comment: Or max(-n,n) instead of abs(n)

Comment: max function and multiplication both make the model nonlinear

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a binary variable (**nlow**) for n beening eighter below or above the interval. Then use two constraints to inforce this. The number **M** should be large egnouf that it does not limit your variable **n**.

```
Scalar M /1000/;    
Integer Variable n;    
Binary Variable nlow;    
Equation below, above;

below ..  n =L= n1 + M*(1-nlow);    
above ..  n =G= n2 - M*nlow;
```